# gooddata How can I get the Identifier of the visualization to be rendered

Tags: javascript, gooddata

I'm trying to render reports using visualization component. How can I get the Identifier of the visualization to be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are speaking about GoodData.UI SDK here.

The easiest way probably would be to use GoodData provided "gdc-catalog-export" as documented here: https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/gdc_catalog_export.html